# GetJson doesn't return anything

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm trying to display some information from a json object. My getJson function doesn't return anything.

I think the problem is that i don't target the right value.

My code:

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Please enter your searchterm:</p>
    <input id="myinput" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="result">

</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON("http://ghost-app.com/api/search?searchterm=pro_wheely",function(data){
        jQuery("#result").prepend('<h3>'+data.players.results[0].username+'</h3>');
    });
});
```

I can view the json file just fine in my browser. [JSON link](http://api.codcp.com/search?searchterm=pro_wheely)

As far as i can tell everything looks right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Javascript has a same-origin policy, and you've just discovered how it's works. You can't get JSON from a cross domain site that doesn't send certain headers or support JSONP, it just can't be done.

Comment: Anything I can do about that?

Comment: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) has some Ajax-specific tips

Comment: Unless you can change the settings on the API you're contacting, no! You can get the data with serverside code, and then do the ajax call to your own server.

Comment: Sounds like too much work for the kind of project i was thinking about. It's an unofficial API anyway so could be taken down any day. Too bad they didn't include a way to retrieve data from cross-domain. I've tried adding `?callback=?` to the url without luck.Thx for the help anyway-